# Accessing multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

After running my code

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('data.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    var line;
    var arr = line.split();
    console.log(arr);
    });
```

is get this return:

```
[ 'n10,1366829460,1366831260,60|37.0,65.0,87.0,41.0,100.0,76.0,83.0,82.0,50.0,54.0,46.0,28.0,68.0,69.0,94.0,90.0,57.0,47.0,94.0,83.0,79.0,85.0,99.0,77.0,85.0,70.0,91.0,88.0,64.0,89.0' ]
[ 'n11,1366829460,1366831260,60|100.0,57.0,84.0,35.0,87.0,67.0,66.0,92.0,39.0,57.0,65.0,65.0,60.0,39.0,89.0,49.0,71.0,77.0,89.0,67.0,74.0,70.0,52.0,69.0,88.0,85.0,99.0,100.0,97.0,97.0' ]
[ 'n12,1366829460,1366831260,60|40.0,35.0,75.0,35.0,62.0,67.0,38.0,31.0,34.0,34.0,57.0,69.0,76.0,38.0,78.0,91.0,76.0,76.0,71.0,88.0,20.0,81.0,58.0,89.0,100.0,70.0,79.0,50.0,54.0,75.0' ]
[ 'n13,1366829460,1366831260,60|73.0,77.0,78.0,42.0,18.0,43.0,43.0,85.0,51.0,61.0,21.0,81.0,50.0,64.0,86.0,40.0,83.0,43.0,28.0,45.0,34.0,55.0,27.0,46.0,44.0,57.0,35.0,69.0,69.0,55.0' ]
```

I'm now attempting to print out the row name (for example 'n10'), and then find the average of the numbers in each of the arrays (for example 'n10: average 50.3'). Any help?

Comment: A function can only return a single value.  What are you talking about?

Comment: What are the 2 numbers after the row name and before the `|`? And show is the code you have so far? How is it returning that data because it doesn't look like properly formed code/arrays.

Comment: var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('Data.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    var line;
    var arr = line.split();
    //s= arr.join("=");
 console.log(arr);
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the data pattern...

Given:

```
var data = 'n10,1366829460,1366831260,60|37.0,65.0,87.0,41.0,100.0,76.0,83.0,82.0,50.0,54.0,46.0,28.0,68.0,69.0,94.0,90.0,57.0,47.0,94.0,83.0,79.0,85.0,99.0,77.0,85.0,70.0,91.0,88.0,64.0,89.0';
```

This is a comma separated list of values (CSV).

It has been indicated, the first value (e.g. 'n10') is the label for each row of data.

After that there are two large integers, which appear to be datetime epochs with the last three digits removed (milliseconds).  When the integers (suffixed with 3 zeros) are converted to dates, I see a difference of one hour between the dates.

Which might explain the next value, 60, as in the number of minutes between the two time stamps.

However, this is where the CSV falls apart.  There is a pipe (|) character after the 60, followed by a list of numbers delimited by commas.  I assume these values are the ones that are to be averaged.

Assuming all this is true, you can easily determine the after for each row.

First the label can be extract by looking for the index of the first comma and getting all the character up to that point:

```
var label = data.substr(0, data.indexOf(','));
```

Next grab all the text after the pipe, and then parse the string into numbers:

```
var numberList = data.substr(data.indexOf('|')+1);
var numbers = JSON.parse('[' + numberList + ']');
var sum = numbers.reduce(function(runningSum, currNum) {
    return runningSum + currNum;
}, 0);
var avg = sum / numbers.length;

console.log('row ' + label + ' has an average of ' + avg);
```

Now all you have to do is loop this logic over each row of your data

```
 dataItems.forEach(function(data) {

  ...

 });
```

Comment: I've added my code to the question, could it be an issue there?

Comment: This answers your problem: you wanted to display each row name with the average of the values.  What part doesn't work for you?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work but i get "Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined" just trying to debug now

Comment: This code isn't mean to run on its own.  It is meant as an example to illustrate what I'm describing you need to do in the text.  You need to fully understand what is going on, and not just copy/paste code around.

Comment: Yeah, i got it, i'm trying to implement the logic

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through and parse the arrays. Something like:

```
var a = [[ 'n10,1366829460,1366831260,60|37.0,65.0,87.0,41.0,100.0,76.0,83.0,82.0,50.0,54.0,46.0,28.0,68.0,69.0,94.0,90.0,57.0,47.0,94.0,83.0,79.0,85.0,99.0,77.0,85.0,70.0,91.0,88.0,64.0,89.0' ]
[ 'n11,1366829460,1366831260,60|100.0,57.0,84.0,35.0,87.0,67.0,66.0,92.0,39.0,57.0,65.0,65.0,60.0,39.0,89.0,49.0,71.0,77.0,89.0,67.0,74.0,70.0,52.0,69.0,88.0,85.0,99.0,100.0,97.0,97.0' ]
[ 'n12,1366829460,1366831260,60|40.0,35.0,75.0,35.0,62.0,67.0,38.0,31.0,34.0,34.0,57.0,69.0,76.0,38.0,78.0,91.0,76.0,76.0,71.0,88.0,20.0,81.0,58.0,89.0,100.0,70.0,79.0,50.0,54.0,75.0' ]
[ 'n13,1366829460,1366831260,60|73.0,77.0,78.0,42.0,18.0,43.0,43.0,85.0,51.0,61.0,21.0,81.0,50.0,64.0,86.0,40.0,83.0,43.0,28.0,45.0,34.0,55.0,27.0,46.0,44.0,57.0,35.0,69.0,69.0,55.0' ]];

a = a.map(function(line){
  return line.split(',');
});
```

You can then do whatever mathematical operations you want on it in the map function.

Comment: That's only part of it.  See the pipe after the '60' value?  If you split only on the commas, you'll miss out on the first value after the pipe.  Also, the pipe prevents it from being parsed into a number "60|100".

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your data is a "list of arrays", called "myTable"

with jQuery you can do something like:

iterate with your data:

```js
var myTable = [ ['N10,1,2|1,2,3'], ['N11,1,2|5,6,7'] ];

$(myTable).each(function (iRow, row) {

  var rowSplit = row[0].split('|');
 
  var avgCount = 0;
  var avgSum = 0;

  $(rowSplit[1].split(',')).each(function (iVal, val) {
    avgCount++;
    avgSum += parseFloat(val);
  });
  
  var out = rowSplit[0].split(',')[0] + " avg " + (avgSum / avgCount);

  document.body.innerHTML += out + "<br>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```